# Solving a system of differential equations with an integral constraint.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here is a system of differential equation I am trying to solve:

$$ u''(x) - a(x) u(x) + b(x) v(x) = 0 \quad (1)$$
$$ \gamma v''(x) + a(x) u(x) - b(x) v(x) = 0 \quad (2) $$

where $a(x)$, $b(x)$ are known functions in $x$ and $\gamma$ is a constant. The following are the boundary conditions:

$$u'(x=0) = u'(x=1) = v'(x=0) = v'(x=1) =0 \quad (3)$$

In order to avoid trivial solutions there is mass conservation constraint as follows:

$$ \int_{0}^{1} (u(x)+v(x))dx = 1 \quad (4)$$

One can apply the constraint of equation 4 using finite differences, by applying the conservation law instead of expanding one of the equations for a particular cell. This allows one to solve the system of equations.

1. **My question is whether any other approach for solving this problem. I want to scale this system into a non-linear system and am hoping to avoid finite difference method.**
2. **Can finite element or shooting method be used to solve this problem in case I wanted to avoid finite differences?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can incorporate the integral into the ODE system as additional component $w$ with
$$
w'=u+v;~~w(x=0)=0,~~w(x=1)=1.
$$

You could try to solve a non-linear BVP symbolically. There is a very good chance that this will prove impossible.

So you need to use numerical methods. There is some large overlap of finite difference methods and low-order collocation methods. Most multiple-shooting BVP solvers are implemented via collocation, leading to large but sparse systems of non-linear equations. Single shooting is also possible for the extended system, but generally less stable, more likely to leave the part of the domain around the solution.

Comment: Yes, numerical methods is what I am looking for. So in this case I can then eliminate one of the flux boundary conditions, right?

Comment: Yes. The first-order system has 5 components, so you need exactly 5 conditions.